# How to show custom option title and value in Magento page?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, orders, invoice

I have created a custom invoice page in magento and want to show custom value and title below ordered product name. Please provide me code to get custom value and title of ordered product.

```
 <?php   
            $items = $this->getorderitems();
            $total = 0;
            foreach ($items as $item) {
             $product = $this->loadproduct($item->getProductId());
             ?>
             <?php echo $item->getName(); ?>
                SKU : <?php echo $item->getSku(); ?>


                <?php echo round($item->getQtyOrdered()); ?>
                <?php 
                echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($item->getBaseRowTotalInclTax(), true, false); 
                $amount = $item->getBaseRowTotalInclTax();
                 $total = $total + $amount;
                  ?>
```

Comment: Pls try : 
$result = array();
        if ($options = $this->getItem()->getProductOptions()) {
            if (isset($options['options'])) {
                $result = array_merge($result, $options['options']);
            }
            if (isset($options['additional_options'])) {
                $result = array_merge($result, $options['additional_options']);
            }
            if (!empty($options['attributes_info'])) {
                $result = array_merge($options['attributes_info'], $result);
            }
        }

Comment: please show ur code?

Comment: not working its giving fatal error

Comment: question edited with code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below collection will give you custom options selected for the order items

```
<?php
$itemBlock = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('sales/order_item_renderer_default');

$items = $this->getorderitems();
$total = 0;
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $product = $this->loadproduct($item->getProductId());

    $itemBlock->setItem($item);
    //get the options 
    $_options = $itemBlock->getItemOptions();
    ?>


    <?php echo $item->getName(); ?>
    SKU : <?php echo $item->getSku(); ?>

    <?php foreach ($_options as $option): ?>
       <strong> <?php echo $option['label']; ?>: </strong>
        <?php echo $option['print_value']; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php echo round($item->getQtyOrdered()); ?>
    <?php
    echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($item->getBaseRowTotalInclTax(), true, false);
    $amount = $item->getBaseRowTotalInclTax();
    $total = $total + $amount;
    ?>
```

Comment: not working code nothing display

Comment: question edited with code

Comment: edited my answer as per your code.

Comment: thanks for your answer its working but one thing is here is sku which is showing i want to show custom option sku if product is order from custom option. if not order from cutom option then it will show main sku of itme

Comment: try to print_r($option) you might be get the sku of custom option also

Comment: dear sir for custom value code is working well but giving this type of output  colorblack. I want to show like this Color : Black and it will be in bold please give me code sir for both sku and this

Comment: updated in my answer check if that help you

Comment: dear sir, also help for sku